# How can I take AWS iam report through email

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ses

I want to use AWS lambda to create an AWS IAM report as an excel file and send it email to me.
So I made this code and it worked. but When I opened this excel file, I noticed that several topics were blank.

last_login, password_age

I want to know why it is blank.

this is my code. Thanks

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import os
from io import BytesIO
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    response = client.list_users()
    users_info = []
    for user in response['Users']:
        username = user['UserName']
        groups = client.list_groups_for_user(UserName=username)['Groups']
        last_login = client.get_login_profile(UserName=username).get('PasswordLastUsed')
        mfa_enabled = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=username).get('MFADevices') != []
        password_age = (pd.Timestamp.now(tz='utc') - pd.Timestamp(last_login)).days if last_login else None
        access_keys = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username).get('AccessKeyMetadata')
        active_key_age = None
        for access_key in access_keys:
            if access_key['Status'] == 'Active':
                active_key_age = (pd.Timestamp.now(tz='utc') - pd.Timestamp(access_key['CreateDate'])).days
                break
        user_info = {
            'Username': username,
            'Groups': ', '.join([group['GroupName'] for group in groups]),
            'Last Login': str(last_login) if last_login else '',
            'MFA Enabled': mfa_enabled,
            'Password Age (Days)': password_age,
            'Active Key Age (Days)': active_key_age
        }
        users_info.append(user_info)
    df = pd.DataFrame(users_info)
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IAM Users Info', index=False, startrow=1)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['IAM Users Info']
    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'valign': 'top',
        'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
        'border': 1
    })
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
        column_len = df[value].astype(str).str.len().max()
        column_len = max(column_len, len(value)) + 3
        worksheet.set_column(col_num, col_num, column_len)
    writer.save()
    from_address = 'my-mail'
    to_address = 'my-mail'
    subject = 'IAM Users Info'
    body = 'Please see the attached file for IAM Users Info.'  
    client = boto3.client('ses')   
    attachment = MIMEApplication(output.getvalue(), _subtype='vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='iam_users_info.xlsx')
    message = MIMEMultipart
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `client.get_login_profile` For `last_login` but it return informations about the login profile of the user not the login activity, use `client.get_user()` instead, also `password_age` calculate the difference between the current timestamp and `last_login` but `last_login` is not retrieved as we want so `password_age` is incorrect as well.

I updated your code like that:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import os
from io import BytesIO
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    response = client.list_users()
    users_info = []
    for user in response['Users']:
        username = user['UserName']
        groups = client.list_groups_for_user(UserName=username)['Groups']
        user_data = client.get_user(UserName=username)
        last_login = user_data['User'].get('PasswordLastUsed')
        mfa_enabled = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=username).get('MFADevices') != []
        password_age = (pd.Timestamp.now(tz='utc') - pd.Timestamp(last_login)).days if last_login else None
        access_keys = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username).get('AccessKeyMetadata')
        active_key_age = None
        for access_key in access_keys:
            if access_key['Status'] == 'Active':
                active_key_age = (pd.Timestamp.now(tz='utc') - pd.Timestamp(access_key['CreateDate'])).days
                break
        user_info = {
            'Username': username,
            'Groups': ', '.join([group['GroupName'] for group in groups]),
            'Last Login': str(last_login) if last_login else '',
            'MFA Enabled': mfa_enabled,
            'Password Age (Days)': password_age,
            'Active Key Age (Days)': active_key_age
        }
        users_info.append(user_info)
    df = pd.DataFrame(users_info)
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IAM Users Info', index=False, startrow=1)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['IAM Users Info']
    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'valign': 'top',
        'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
        'border': 1
    })
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
        column_len = df[value].astype(str).str.len().max()
        column_len = max(column_len, len(value)) + 3
        worksheet.set_column(col_num, col_num, column_len)
    writer.save()
    from_address = 'my-mail'
    to_address = 'my-mail'
    subject = 'IAM Users Info'
    body = 'Please see the attached file for IAM Users Info.'  
    client = boto3.client('ses')   
    attachment = MIMEApplication(output.getvalue(), _subtype='vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='iam_users_info.xlsx')
    message = MIMEMultipart
```